# Pulover Macro Creator: WinActivate using only part of the title

Tags: macros, autohotkey

How do you use WinActivate using only part of the title in Pulover's Macro Creator?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a start:

> SetTitleMatchMode
>
> Sets the matching behavior of the WinTitle parameter in commands such as WinWait.
>
> SetTitleMatchMode, MatchMode
>
> MatchMode
>
> One of the following digits or the word RegEx:
>
> 1: A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.
>
> 2: A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.
>
> 3: A window's title must exactly match WinTitle to be a match.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm